# Target input field by name using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an input field that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted[event_email]" value="">
```

I was trying to change the value of it and tried this:

```
jQuery('submitted[event_email]').val('test');
```

I would like to target it by the name, but i am not sure what i did wrong. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Your selector is targeting an element of type 'submitted' with attribute `event_email` setted, you need to target name attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** [name="value"]

Also from the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

So you can do:

```
jQuery('input[name="submitted\\[event_email\\]"]').val('test');
```

---

But actually you don't need to escape the `[ ]` here since it's wrapping in quotes:

```
jQuery('[name="submitted[event_email]"]').val('test');
```

Comment: Ahhh yes... escaping the `[` `]` threw me off. I knew it was something stupid. thank you!

Comment: You don't need any escaping here because string is wrapped inside quotes. I mean, this will work too: `jQuery('input[name="submitted[event_email]"]').val('test');` See: http://jsfiddle.net/pn4Zs/

Answer (score 3):

You need to to escape `[` and  `]` using `\`  but `\` is also special character so we escape it also.

so we escape using `\\`

```
jQuery('[name="submitted\\[event_email\\]"]').val('test');
```

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

---

**Update**

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/63bnP/)

There is no need to escape `[` and `]` as it is wrapped in quotes (i.e It is string)

```
jQuery('[name="submitted[event_email]"]').val('test');
//            ^                      ^
```

Comment: No, no need to escape anything here